# How can I create a new column containing the same values as a groupby in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset that I need to create a new column for. This new column needs to be equivalent to a value found in a `groupby`.

For example:

I have this dataframe:

```
data = [
    ["A", 1, "special","aaa", 64],
    ["A", 1,"special", "bbb", 140],
    ["A", 2,"notspecial", "aaa", 25],
    ["A", 2,"notspecial", "bbb", 12],
    ["A", 3,"notspecial", "aaa", 85],
    ["A", 3,"notspecial", "bbb", 10],
    ["B", 1,"special", "ccc", 200],
    ["B", 2,"notspecial", "ccc", 350],
    ["B", 3,"notspecial", "ccc", 500],
    ["B", 4,"notspecial", "ccc", 651],

]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", "Subset", "Description","Category", "Value"])
df
```

[image]

I need to create a version of this dataset with a new column, this new column needs to be the `Value` for the `special` row grouped by `ID` and `Category`. (note that in some cases, there won't be multiple categories, and in some there will be). Basically that whole column contains only `special` values for the `ID` and `Category` groupby. Like below:

```
data = [
    ["A", 1, "special", "aaa", 64, 64],
    ["A", 1, "special", "bbb", 140, 140],
    ["A", 2, "notspecial", "aaa", 25, 64],
    ["A", 2, "notspecial", "bbb", 12, 140],
    ["A", 3, "notspecial", "aaa", 85, 64],
    ["A", 3, "notspecial", "bbb", 10, 140],
    ["B", 1, "special", "ccc", 200, 200],
    ["B", 2, "notspecial", "ccc", 350, 200],
    ["B", 3, "notspecial", "ccc", 500, 200],
    ["B", 4, "notspecial", "ccc", 651, 200],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=["ID", "Subset", "Description", "Category", "Value", "special_value"]
)
df
```

[image]

I previously used:

```
# create new column dedicated to untreated mean raw value severity values across trial ids
df["special_value"] = (
    df.where(
        df["Description"].eq("special")
    )
    .groupby(["ID", "Category"])["Value"]
    .transform("mean")
)
```

but this only works when the `groupby` is just `ID` NOT when I add `Category` in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: I do not really get it. Can you include the expected output?

Comment: I did with the second screenshot and dataframe! The `special_value` column is the new column I am trying to create. I am also adding some edits that should hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.transform` with `first`:

```
df["special_value"] = df["Value"][df["Description"].eq("special")]
df["special_value"] = df.groupby("Category")["special_value"].transform("first")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  ID  Subset Description Category  Value  special_value
0  A       1     special      aaa     64           64.0
1  A       1     special      bbb    140          140.0
2  A       2  notspecial      aaa     25           64.0
3  A       2  notspecial      bbb     12          140.0
4  A       3  notspecial      aaa     85           64.0
5  A       3  notspecial      bbb     10          140.0
6  B       1     special      ccc    200          200.0
7  B       2  notspecial      ccc    350          200.0
8  B       3  notspecial      ccc    500          200.0
9  B       4  notspecial      ccc    651          200.0
```

Comment: ahh so this is soooo close. the only problem, is that it isn't working for the case where there are not multiple categories, i.e ID B.

Comment: @user Can you explain a bit more? Or even better, update your sample to reflect such cases ;)

Comment: oh my goodness, my mistake, will do that right now! I believe it's reflected in `ID` = B, `category = `ccc`. When I ran the code you included I got all np.nan values instead of 200. Thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: I thought the sample's `ccc`'s first row was typo (it's unspecial whereas output is special) but perhaps i'm mistaken. Do you explicitly have to convert the first row of each group to special if it isn't already?

Comment: oh man I am the worst, you're right. I got frazzled and panicked. I just corrected it. I am so sorry for that.

Comment: Hm.. with the updated sample, I get the expected output :(

Comment: Nope you’re right! My mistakes continue. Thank you !!!! (Sorry again)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, if you wanted the first value of ID and Category, otherwise you could do the same creating, dfm, using groupby:

```
dfm =df.query("Description =='special").drop_duplicates(['ID','Category'])[['ID', 'Category', 'Value']]\
       .rename(columns={'Value':'special_value_comp'})
df.merge(dfm, on=['ID', 'Category']).sort_values(['ID', 'Subset'])
```

Output:

```
  ID  Subset Description Category  Value  special_value  special_value_comp
0  A       1     special      aaa     64             64                  64
3  A       1     special      bbb    140            140                 140
1  A       2  notspecial      aaa     25             64                  64
4  A       2  notspecial      bbb     12            140                 140
2  A       3  notspecial      aaa     85             64                  64
5  A       3  notspecial      bbb     10            140                 140
6  B       1     special      ccc    200            200                 200
7  B       2  notspecial      ccc    350            200                 200
8  B       3  notspecial      ccc    500            200                 200
9  B       4  notspecial      ccc    651            200                 200
```

Comment: @user  Yep, I forgot that condition.

Comment: @user Happy coding!  Be safe and stay healthy.

Answer (score 0):

One more nasty way

```
df.loc[df['Description'] != 'special', 'Value'] = np.nan
df['special_value'] = df.groupby(["ID", "Category"]).Value.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```